# I need php to be able to connect to a linux server

Tags: php, linux, ssh, putty, tunnel

Hi I installed the ssh2 library which is PECL and on the wamp server it shows a tick against the library showing that the library is installed however when i try and establish a connection with ssh and php it keeps saying ssh2 function is undefined what is the problem?

Comment: silly question, but did you restart WAMP?

Comment: No was I supposed to also install the OpenSSL and libssh2?